# how to animate using jquery.path

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to create an image animation using `jquery.path`

```
<body>
<img id="elem" src="img/01.png" alt="img">

<script src='../jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery.path.js'></script>
<script src='enter.js'></script>
</body>
```

enter.js

```
var arc_params = {
    center: [285,185],  
    radius: 100,    
    start: 30,
    end: 200,
    dir: -1
};

$("#elem").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)});
```

css

```
#elem{
    display:block;
    margin:30% auto;
    width:120px;
}
```

Image is there, but nothing happens. There is no any animation. Console is free.

Comment: Try a lower version of jQuery.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined" on the [jQuery.path demo page](http://weepy.github.io/jquery.path/) in Chrome 36.0.1985.125.

Comment: @showdev, yes, I'm using Chrome 36... I think you didn't place script in correct stack - `jquery core` - `jquery.path` - `your code`.

Comment: I get the error on the [demo page](http://weepy.github.io/jquery.path/) for jQuery.path. I didn't code it. Here's a [bug report](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path/issues/26). But this may not be relevant to your issue if you are not getting any javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't enough reputation to comment so I take this way.
I have tried the demo page of jquery.path. Only **Firefox** is able to display the elements and their animation on that page, **all others** did not even display the elements. It seems to be a bug in the plugin not in the browsers.